Can't get SCOM rule to run locally on target
I'm using SCOM 2019 and am trying to author a new rule that is a Probe Based Script (Performance) with a vbscript that returns a property bag. The rule is assigned to objects that have the SCOM agent running and I've tested the script locally on the targets.
My challenge is that I can't get the rule to run locally on the targets, the evidence of this is that the script logs to the event log of the SCOM Management Server. Additionally, when I edit the management pack xml and set the rule with Remotable="false", I then get the following event log on the SCOM Management Server:

Rule/Monitor "{ruleid}" running for remote instance "{instance}" with id:"{id}" will be disabled as it is not remotable. Management group "{mg}".

Am I missing something here to have the rule run locally on the target?
Edit : The target is a group, I think I'm starting to understand that the script will run with reference to the group and not the elements that make up the group. If this is the case, do I need to somehow create a class (rather than a group) that has Microsoft.Windows.Computer as its base?

Confirmed as I suspected that when targeting a group the script runs with the reference to the group and not the elements of the group. The solution is to create a class that is populated with the desired targets and then to target the rule at the group.
There are lots of great fragments here that show how to create classes (Class and Discovery):
https://github.com/thekevinholman/FragmentLibrary
